# Stack Exchange Career, at "Improve your CV" I am asked "Link to a Stack Exchange network account" but "StackExchange" is excluded from that list :-(

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, jobs, stack-exchange, hyperlinks

Stack Exchange Career. At the tip section "Improve your CV" in the right upper corner, I am asked "Link to a Stack Exchange network account",

But "Stack Exchange" itself is excluded from that list :-(. The offer is just

- Stack Overflow
- Project Management
- MathOverflow
- Software Quality Assurance & Testing
- Super User

though I use the same e-mail address for all sites. And there is no "add" option for manual adding Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 4):

The Stack Exchange *network* is composed of a individual sites. It looks like your network account is linked, and you now have the option to include individual sites you participate on on your CV.

Stack Exchange (as in stackexchange.com) isn't a site in itself, just a read-only portal for viewing/aggregating one's network activity.

If you're talking about *Meta* Stack Exchange, I believe we also exclude meta sites since it's the main Q&A sites that matter.

Answer (score 3):

Since Careers only focuses on technical jobs (like programming, software testing, etc.) only those sites are shown that directly relate to the purpose of Careers.

All sites you can link are technical sites that fit the profile of Careers. All others are excluded. If Careers gets opened for other types of jobs, those sites will be made available to link.